# Html5 video recording and upload?

Tags: html, html5-video, webrtc

I need to create an app that can record video using a webcam or mobile camera (it needs to be cross platform).

So far I have written a small proof of concept using webrtc getusermedia. It can record the video and playback but I am not sure how to get the file to upload back to the server.

Here is a link to this sample http://jsfiddle.net/3FfUP/

And the javascript code:

```
(function ($) {
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
navigator.getUserMedia  = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
            navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;
var video = document.querySelector('video');
var onFailSoHard = function(e) {
    console.log('Reeeejected!', e);
};
$('#capture-button').click (function () {
    console.log ("capture click!");
    if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
        // Not showing vendor prefixes.
        navigator.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true}, function(localMediaStream) {
            var video = document.querySelector('video');
            video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(localMediaStream);

            // Note: onloadedmetadata doesn't fire in Chrome when using it with getUserMedia.
            // See crbug.com/110938.
            video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
                // Ready to go. Do some stuff.
            };
        }, onFailSoHard);
    } else {
        video.src = 'somevideo.webm'; // fallback.
    }
});
$('#stop-button').click (function (e) {
    video.pause ();
    localMediaStream.stop ();
});
})(jQuery);
```

How can I get what is recorded in this sample as a file so that it can be uploaded to the server.

Comment: Eric Bidelman describes a method for recording .webm from getUserMedia: http://ericbidelman.tumblr.com/post/31486670538/creating-webm-video-from-getusermedia. recorder.js (or even RecorderJS) might also be useful.

Comment: There is a W3C working draft proposal for recording API at [http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-media-capture/2012Dec/att-0159/RecordingProposal.html](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-media-capture/2012Dec/att-0159/RecordingProposal.html) However, neither [Firefox](http://www.webrtc.org/firefox#TOC-Recording-API) nor Chrome have implemented it yet. It looks promising though.

Answer (score 7):

Hi sorry if this is kinda late, but here is how i managed to make the file upload to a server, I really don't have an idea if this is the best way to achieve this but i hope it helps to give you a clue.Following the tutorial Eric Bidelman wrote (as Sam Dutton commented) what you get is a blob, so I made a XMLHttpRequest to get the video and set the response type as blob, afterwards I created a FormData in which I appended the response, this will allow the blob to be sent to the server.Here is how my function looks like.

```
function sendXHR(){
    //Envia bien blob, no interpretado
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var video=$("#myexportingvideo");
    xhr.open('GET', video.src , true);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.onload = function(e) {
    if (this.status == 200) {
        // Note: .response instead of .responseText
        var blob = new Blob([this.response], {type: 'video/webm'});
        console.log(blob.size/1024);
        console.log(blob.type);
        form = new FormData(),
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        form.append("myblob",blob,"Capture.webm");
        form.append("myname",$("#name_test").value);
        request.open("POST","./UploadServlet",true);
        request.send(form);
       }
    };
    xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: This seems like it should work, but I get a 404 status when trying to fetch the BLOB. My question and code can be viewed here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27707322/xmlhttprequest-status-of-404-with-blob-url

Answer (score 2):

You can record [video](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/getusermedia/record-user-webm.html) and [audio](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs) separately. You can get files (WAV/WebM) and upload them on demand. webkitMediaStream takes two objects 1) audioTracks and 2) videoTracks. You may be able to combine both audio/video recorded streams!

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm a few years late to the party, but here is a snippet that's capable of capturing video and uploading it to the included node.js server as a webm file. I've tested in Chrome and Firefox.

https://gist.github.com/rissem/d51b1997457a7f6dc4cf05064f5fe984

Answer (score -3):

The only **cross platform** web video recorder is the [HDFVR webcam video recorder software](http://hdfvr.com).

It uses Flash (records using Flash codecs + streams to a media server) on the desktop and the HTML Media Capture API (record using OS + upload to webserver) on mobile to record video from pretty much any desktop or mobile browser.

You can link it to a ffmpeg installation to convert everything to a cross platform format like MP4 (iOS records to a .mov container that doesn't play on Android) and it also has a JS API.

Comment: Can I use it without installing media server as i need only to record and save video to server ?

Comment: `The only cross platform...` is obviously untrue(at least now) when HTML5 supports it.
http://www.w3.org/TR/mediastream-recording/.

Comment: Media Recorder API does not yet work on IE, Edge & Safari https://addpipe.com/blog/mediarecorder-api/