# XMLHttpRequest Status of 404 With Blob URL

Tags: javascript, html, video, blob, bloburls

I'm trying to upload a blob URL generated by getUserMedia to the server.
[Someone else wanted to do the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14976460/html5-video-recording-and-upload), and that question has been answered.

I am using the same code for the XHR request as the person who answered that question, but I'm getting a 404. [I made a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/auoyjhzv/4/), and the same thing happens when you look at the console. I have a [live example on my site as well](http://html5.rickyyoder.x10.mx/lab/videoRecording/), and the same thing happens.

Here is the piece of code that needs some TLC:

```
function XHR(){
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET',record.src); //404 ???
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.onload = function(e) {
    if (this.status == 200){
        //do some stuff
        result.innerText = this.response;
    }
};
xhr.send();
}
```

Everybody else seems to be able to do this, because this has been discussed before.

[Exhibit A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876175/how-to-get-a-file-or-blob-from-an-object-url)

[Exhibit B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14952052/convert-blob-url-to-normal-url)

I'm using ChromeOS, 41.0.2252.2 dev. What exactly is going on, and why can't I get the blob?

Comment: You are trying to use the XMLHttpRequest to load a blob??? Why? What is the blob?

Comment: Well, the first link I put in the body of my post shows someone who wanted to upload a getUserMedia BLOB to the server. That's what I want to do as well.

Comment: Well your code is not uploading it to a server.... You are making a request to that src...unless I am reading the code wrong. PLUS you probably want to be using a POST and not a get due to file size.

Comment: I know. But you can't put the carriage before the horse. I need to know why I get a status of 404 when trying to get a BLOB URL before I can even think of uploading to server.

Comment: I'm not sure. The code I saw used GET to retrieve the contents of the BLOB, and then POST to upload to the server.

Comment: I don't believe you understand what I am asking. I know how to get/send data with AJAX. My question is why am I getting a 404 not found error for a BLOB URL?

Comment: Can you show us what `record.src` is? I cannot try your code in Firefox.

Comment: If you try the Fiddle I have in my post, the source is a BLOB URL. (blob://). The source is generated using window.URL.createObjectURL(mediaStream);

Answer (score 1):

I'm almost certain the media in a MediaStream isn't saved anywhere, just thrown away after use.
There is a API in the works to record streams, [`MediaRecorder`](http://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-record/MediaRecorder.html) .
Only Firefox has the most basic implementation of this so it isn't usable as yet.
If you're implementing this on a mobile device you can use a file input with the capture attribute.

```
<input type="file" accept="video/*" capture>
```

Comment: But then I don't understand. What about the first link in my post? What browser were they referring to?

Comment: Another thing I'd like to add: They DO seem to be thrown away after use, but that doesn't make any sense. BLOB URLs are supposed to be "in-memory". Kinda like false advertising--a BLOB that's just tossed instead of kept!

Answer (score 0):

```
function XHR(){
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET","record.src",true); // adding true will make it work asynchronously
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.onload = function(e) {
    if (this.status == 200){
        //do some stuff
        result.innerText = this.response;
    }
};
xhr.send();
}
```

Try now! it should work.

Comment: Sorry I took so long to get back to this question. This still does not work. I honestly don't understand why this has been talked about before when it doesn't even work!

Answer (score 0):

look at this post: 
[Html5 video recording and upload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14976460/html5-video-recording-and-upload)

What you are missing is the declaration of what "blob" is. First thing this person does inside the .onload function() is 
    `var blob = new Blob([this.response], {type: 'video/webm'});`